# Test NG filters only group in the first test in the suite

Tags: testng

I'm running TestNG and I'm trying to run only specific group from the all suite attach, but only the first test gets filtered by group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Managemenet" parallel="methods" thread-count="100" preserve-order="false"  >
<test verbose="2" name="Chen Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="100" >
     <groups>
          <define name="Sanity">
              <include name="mgmt_sanity"></include>
          </define>
         <define name="Regression">
              <include name="mgmt_regression"></include>
              <include name="mgmt_sanity"></include>
          </define>
         <define name="Smoke">
              <include name="mgmt_smoke"></include>
          </define>

    </groups>


    <classes>
        <class name="com.chen.auto.mgmt.chenTests">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test verbose="2" name="Dudu Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="100" >
     <groups>
          <define name="Sanity">
              <include name="mgmt_sanity"></include>
          </define>
         <define name="Regression">
              <include name="mgmt_regression"></include>
              <include name="mgmt_sanity"></include>
          </define>
         <define name="Smoke">
              <include name="mgmt_smoke"></include>
          </define>

    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.chen.auto.mgmt.dudu">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

There is a similar [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494027/running-multiple-testng-tests-by-defining-groups-from-command-line), but without an answer.
It looks like a bug. As result, I cannot use ReportNG, even with all parallel option.

Does someone how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) you can define [groups of groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups), which is what you seam to be doing. However, this just creates groups, you still need to define which groups to run, by specifying `<run>` element:

```
<test name="MyTest">
  <groups>
    <define name="GroupOfGroups1">
      <include name="group1"/>
      <include name="group2"/>
    </define>

    <define name="all">
      <include name="GroupOfGroups"/>
      <include name="group3"/>
    </define>

    <run>
      <include name="all"/>
    </run>
  </groups>

  <classes>
    <class name="org.test.MyTest"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

This defines all the test that should be executed by TestNG invoker. Parallel setting has no influence on which tests are included in the run, but rather how those selected test will be executed. You can read more about [parallel running](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) of tests in TestNG in the same [documentation page](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need to run several tests in the same xml suit (in the <test> i will define groups of groups). with your answer i cannot run several tests, only one <test> and this is my issue. when i'm running several <tests> the testNG group filter will work fine only on the first <test> after that it wont filtered

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to testNg 6.7 - it will fix your problem for sure.